# （python） labeling points which are in the similar region of a 3-D coordinate system

Tags: python

There are 2000+ points in a 3-D sapce (as picture 1) . The points are classified into 7 groups by K-Means methods.
the points in  picture 1 are presented like this:

```
point_ID_1    x        y        z       group_label
    1       0.254    0.025      0.007        1
    2       0.201    0.078      0.081        1
    3       0.106    0.153      0.238        2
    4       0.052    0.015      0.084        3
    5       0.078    0.005      0.159        7
   ...       ...      ...        ...         ...
```

[image]

there are other 5000+ points in the same 3-D sapce (as picture 2) . The (x,y,z) of points in the picture 2 is different from the points in the picture 2. But their distribution ranges are very similar.

[image]

the point in picture are presented as :

```
point_ID_2    x        y          z       
    1       0.354    0.025      0.028       
    2       0.125    0.128      0.324
    3       0.068    0.292      0.221
    4       0.051    0.086      0.128
    5       0.028    0.081      0.082
   ...       ...      ...        ...
```

I want to label the points in the same region of picture 2 and picture 1 with the same label, as the picture 3 shows.
[image]

Noted that the points are not in the same surface but in a 3-D space

How can I do this? I searched the Internet for a long time but I didn’t find any solutions. Please help me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

When you classified the first 2000 points in a group with Kmeans you obtained a classifier. You can use this classifier to decide for the other 5000 points in which group they belong.
If you used the Kmeans from `scipy`, then you can use the function `sklearn.cluster.KMeans.predict()` for this.

You can find information about this in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need !